# Abstract class fields redundancy C#

Tags: c#, inheritance, abstract

I have base abstract `Goods` class and inherited `Book` class.

```
abstract class Goods
{
    public decimal weight; 
    string Title, BarCode;
    double Price;
    public Goods(string title, string barCode, double price)
    {
        Title = title;
        BarCode = barCode;
        Price = price;
    }
}

abstract class Book : Goods
{
    protected int NumPages;
    public Book(string title, string barCode, double price, int numPages)
        : base(title, barCode, price)
    {
        NumPages = numPages;
        weight = 1;
    }
    public override void display()
    {
        base.display();
        Console.WriteLine("Page Numbers:{0}", NumPages);
    }

}
```

Should I write `title`, `barCode`, `price` that exist in the `Goods` class twice? Can I replace this

```
 public Book(string title, string barCode, double price, int numPages)
        : base(title, barCode, price)
```

with less redundant construction?

Comment: Just a note. You have **fields** and not **properties**. Properties should have `get` and/or `set`.

Comment: Please use `decimal` (or integers) instead of `double` to represent prices.

Comment: I'd consider replacing the abstract class by an interface.

Comment: You already have an accepted answer but consider also: 1) you have PROTECTED FIELDS. Is there a good, great, incredible unavoidable reason for that? 2) public constructor in an abstract class? You may want to make it protected (just for intent, no other reasonable differences) 3) why weight is a string? 4) You may consider to have just a parameterless constructor and let caller fill the object PROPERTIES step by step (if applicable). If not at least you may want to make them read-only properties (else you will have same issues of a parameterless ctor but without advantages)

Comment: I replaced weight with rank. I noticed that. This is not my code. And this is not string. This rank is for sorting through LINQ. I changed it. It can work with string but I want to do it right. Same answer to protected code, Is there some specific examples for 4)?

Comment: According to [edit history](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/37938555/revisions) it was (both protected  fields and string) but OK, _now_ you fixed. Examples? Generated code for EF and usage of WPF/WinForms controls (just to mention two).

Answer (score 17, accepted):

No, this code is not redundant. You must pass values to both `Book` constructor and `base` constructor.

I see you assign `weight` in `Book` constructor. If you want, you can do the same for other `Title`, `BarCode` and `Price` as well. Then your `Goods` constructor would be empty. But That would mean that each implementation of `Goods` would have to do it (which would be a bad thing if there is more logic then simple assign)..

Comment: Your code is not redundant and you cannot make your contructor shorter. That's how C# sintax looks.

Comment: I understood. Books constructor inherits values from base Goods constructor as base.And they pass from base constructor to inherited constructor. Instead of filling them evertime.

Answer (score 2):

> Should I write title, barCode, price that exist in the Goods class twice? 
>   Can I replace this ... with less redundant construction?

There is *no* "redundancy" in this code.

This is the declaration of your constructor [method], specifying the arguments that it takes.

```
public Book(string title, string barCode, double price, int numPages)
```

This is the invocation of the base class' constructor, passing the arguments passed to *this* constructor.

```
    : base(title, barCode, price)
```

This is absolutely necessary because your base class can *only* be constructed using the constructor provided that takes three arguments.  You *have* to provide these argument, either from arguments passed to this constructor or, possibly, by deriving them, as in

```
    : base(title, barCode, priceDerivedFrom( title, barCode ) )
```

(Not sure how such a function function would work but, hopefully, you see my point).

Comment: Thanks. Invocaton. I understood in another answer but thank you! Word invocation.